# When does this semimetric induced by a quasi-arithmetic mean fulfil the triangle inequality?

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, convex-analysis, means, monotone-functions

> *Definition.* For a continuous, [strictly monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#In_calculus_and_analysis) function $f \colon I \to J$, where $I, J \subset \mathbb R$ are intervals, we can define the [$f$-mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-arithmetic_mean#Definition) of two numbers $p, q \in I$ as
> $$
> M_f \colon I \to I, \qquad (p, q)
> \mapsto f^{-1}\left( \frac{f(p) + f(q)}{2}\right).
> $$
> If $f$ is either (increasing and strictly concave) or (decreasing and [strictly convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition)) on $I$, then the induced [semimetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Semimetrics) is
> $$
> D_f \colon I \times I \to [0, \infty), \qquad (p, q) \mapsto \sqrt{p + q - 2 M_f(p, q)}.
> $$

*Remark (Properties of $D_f$).*
$D_f$ is clearly symmetric.
Furthermore, it is [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition): $D_f(p, p) = \sqrt{p + p - 2 p} = 0$ and $D_f(p, q) = 0$ if and only if $f\left(\frac{p + q}{2}\right) = \frac{f(p) + f(q)}{2}$ if and only if $p = q$ by the strict concavity / convexity of $f$.

*Example 1.*
If $I = (0, \infty)$ and $f = \ln$, then
\begin{align*}
M_{\ln}(p, q)
& = \exp\left(\frac{1}{2} \ln(p) + \frac{1}{2} \ln(q) \right)
= \exp\left(\ln(\sqrt{p}) + \ln(\sqrt{q})\right) \\
& = \exp(\ln(\sqrt{p})) \exp(\ln(\sqrt{q}))
= \sqrt{p} \sqrt{q}
\end{align*}
and so $D_{\ln}(p, q) = | \sqrt{p} - \sqrt{q} |$, which is a metric.

### How can we characterise the functions $f$ such that $D_f$ fulfills the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition)?

*Examples.*

- If $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $I = (0, \infty)$, then $M_f(p, q) = \frac{1}{\frac{\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}}{2}} = \frac{2 p q}{p + q}$ and $$D_f(p, q) = \sqrt{p + q - \frac{4 p q}{p + q}} = \frac{| p - q |}{\sqrt{p + q}}$$ might fulfill the triangle inequality.
- If $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $I = [0, \infty)$, then $M_f(p, q) = \frac{1}{4} (\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})^2$ and $D_f(p, q) = \sqrt{p + q - \frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | \sqrt{p} - \sqrt{q} |$ is a metric.
- Other choices of $f$ could be $x \mapsto a^{-x}$ for $0 < a < 1$ or $x^{-p}$ for $p \ge 1$ or $x \mapsto x - e^{-x} + 1$.

---

Yet another perspective: since $M_f(P,P)=P$, we can write
$D_f(P,Q)=\sqrt{M_f(P,P)+M_f(Q,Q)−2M_f(P,Q)}$, which is reminiscent of a metric build from a kernel function $M$.

---

The second part of the above definition is inspired by section 1.3 of the paper [Quantum Optimal Transport for Tensor Field Processing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08731) (arXiv link, published not-open access version [here](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0956792517000274)) and through answers to this question I hope to make progress on [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535569/interpreting-geometric-mean-exp-frac12-logp-frac12-logq), that is, to find out whether the "quantum analog" of $D_f$ is a metric for the case for $f = \log$, that is, whether
$$
D \colon \mathcal S_+^d \times \mathcal S_+^d \to [0, \infty), \qquad
(P, Q) \mapsto \sqrt{\text{tr}\left(P + Q - 2 \exp\left(\frac{1}{2} \log(P) + \frac{1}{2} \log(Q)\right)\right)}
$$
is a metric, where $\mathcal S_+^d$ is the cone of [symmetric positive semidefinite matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Definitions_for_real_matrices) in $\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, see also the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535569/interpreting-geometric-mean-exp-frac12-logp-frac12-logq?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the interpretation of the $M_{\ln}$ part.
We at least have that $\ln$ is operator monotone and operator concave.
Maybe this distance is related to the [Bures-Wasserstein distance of positive definite matrices](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01504.pdf)?
This construction is also reminiscent of the metric $d$ in [An extension of Kakutani’s theorem on infinite product measures to the tensor product of semifinite $w^*$-algebras by Donald Bures](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-135-00/S0002-9947-1969-0236719-2/).

---

Some ideas to prove that $D(p, q) := \frac{| p - q |}{\sqrt{p + q}}$ fulfills the triangle inequality:

*Case 1: $p > s > q$.*
Then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{p + s}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{p + q}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{s + q}}$, so
\begin{align*}
D(p, q) + D(q, s)
& = \frac{p - q}{\sqrt{p + q}} + \frac{s - q}{\sqrt{s + q}}
> \frac{p - q}{\sqrt{p + q}} + \frac{s - q}{\sqrt{p + q}}
> \frac{p - q}{\sqrt{p + q}} - \frac{s - q}{\sqrt{p + q}} \\
& = \frac{p - s}{\sqrt{p + q}}
> \frac{p - s}{\sqrt{p + s}}
= D(p, s).
\end{align*}
But I haven't been able to use the same strategy for the other cases.

Comment: I'm not sure how related this is, but there are some superficial similarities to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4425777/253966); the techniques used in some of those answers might be able to help you for specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: if the left endpoint of $f(I)$ is $0$, then it is *sufficient* that $(f^{-1})''$ is [log-convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function).**

---

Based on @Carl Schildkraut's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4427253/545914) and a comment by @Martin R on the other answer to that question we can deduce the following necessary condition (on top of the constraints placed on $f$ in the question), where **we require that** (can this be relaxed?) the left endpoint of $J := f(I)$ is $0$ and that $I \subset [0, \infty)$.

> Let $f_0 := f^{-1} \colon J \to I$. If $f_0$ and $\ln \circ (f_0'')$ are convex, then $D_f$ is a metric on $I \times I$.

*Remark.*
Since $f \colon I \to J$ is bijective and either (strictly convex and decreasing) or (strictly concave and increasing), we automatically have that $f^{-1}$ is strictly convex, see e.g. [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Strictly_Increasing_Strictly_Concave_Real_Function_is_Strictly_Convex).
Hence $f_0''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in J$, so that $\ln \circ (f_0'')$ is well-defined.

*Examples.*

- The above conditions are (nearly, see below) satisfied for the functions $f \colon (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$, $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$, $f \colon (0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$, $x \mapsto \ln(x)$ and $f \colon [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$, $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ I mentioned above, which have the inverse functions $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, $f^{-1}(x) = e^x$ and $f^{-1}(x) = x^2$, respectively, such that $(\ln \circ f_0'')(x)$ is equal to $\ln(2) - 3 \ln(x)$, $x$, and $\ln(2)$ respectively.
  *Note that for the logarithm, the endpoint condition is not fulfilled, but the corresponding semimetric still satisfies the triangle inequality*
- The function $f_a \colon \mathbb R \to (0, \infty)$, $x \mapsto a^x$ for $a \in (0, 1)$ is strictly decreasing and convex. We have $f_a^{-1}(x) = \ln_a(x)$ and thus $(f_a^{-1})''(x) = - \frac{1}{x^2 \ln(a)}$ and hence $(\ln \circ f_0'')(x) = 2 \ln(x) \ln(-\ln(a))$.
  This function is convex if and only if $\ln(-\ln(a)) \le 0$, i.e. $a \ge \frac{1}{e}$.
  Note that the edge is case is exactly $f_{\frac{1}{e}}(x) = e^{-x}$.
- The function $f_p \colon (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$, $x \mapsto x^{-\frac{1}{p}}$ for $p \ne 0$ is strictly convex and decreasing for $p > 0$ and strictly concave and increasing for $p < - 1$. Its inverse if $f_p^{-1}(x) = x^{-p}$, which has the second derivative $(f_{p}^{-1})''(x) = p (p + 1) x^{- p - 2}$, whose logarithm $\ln((f_p^{-1})''(x)) = \ln(p (p + 1)) - (p + 2) \ln(x)$ is convex if and only if $p \ge - 2$, so the induced semimetric fulfills the triangle inequality for $p \in (-2, -1) \cup (0, \infty)$.
- The function $f \colon [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$, $x \mapsto \sinh^{-1}(x)$ is strictly increasing and concave. Its inverse is $f_0(x) = \sinh(x)$, which has second derivative $f_0''(x) = \sinh(x)$, whose logarithm $\ln(\sinh(x)) = \ln\left(\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}\right)$ is *concave*, as $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \ln(\sinh(x)) = - \text{csch}^2(x) \le 0$.

*Proof.*
Let $$g \colon I \times I \to I, \qquad (u, v) \mapsto f_0''(u + v)$$
and $u, v, s, t \in I$ such that $u \ge s$ and $v \ge t$.
Now define
$$x_1 := u + v, \quad
x_2 := s + t, \quad 
y_1 := \max(s + v, t + u) \quad \text{and} \quad
y_2 := \min(s + v, t + u).
$$
Then $(x_1, x_2)$ *majorizes* $(y_1, y_2)$ because

- $x_1 \ge x_2$ and $y_1 \ge y_2$,
- $x_1 \ge y_1$,
- $x_1 + x_2 = y_1 + y_2$.

As $\ln(f_0'')$ is convex by assumption, [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality) states that
$$
\ln(f_0''(x_1)) + \ln(f_0''(x_2))
\ge \ln(f_0''(y_1)) + \ln(f_0''(y_2)),
$$
that is,
$$
\ln\big(g(u, v) g(s, t)\big)
\ge \ln\big(g(s, v) g(t, u)\big),
$$
which, due to $\ln$ being strictly montonically increasing, is equivalent to
$$
g(u, v) g(s, t)
\ge g(s, v) g(t, u).
$$
Now, by @Carl Schildkraut's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4427253/545914) the function
\begin{align*}
h(x, y)
& = \sqrt{\int_{x}^{y} \int_{x}^{y} g(u, v) \; \text{d}u \text{ d}v}
= \sqrt{\int_{x}^{y} \int_{x}^{y} f_0''(u + v) \; \text{d}u \text{ d}v} \\
& = \sqrt{f_0(2 x) + f_0(2 y) - 2 f_0(x + y)}.
\end{align*}
fulfills the triangle inequality.

The proof is now completed by noting that
$$
h(x, y)
= D_f\big(f_0(2 x), f_0(2 y)\big).
$$
Indeed, let $p_1, p_2, p_3 \in I$.
Then for $x_k := \frac{1}{2} f(p_k) \in J$ (here we need $\frac{1}{2} J \subset J$, which in our case implies that the left endpoint of $J$ has to be $0$) we have $p_k = f_0(2 x_k)$ for $k \in \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$.
Hence
\begin{align}
D_f(p_1, p_2) + D_f(p_2, p_3)
& = D_f\big(f_0(2 x_1), f_0(2 x_2)\big) + D_f\big(f_0(2 x_2), f_0(2 x_3)\big) \\
& = h(x_1, x_2) + h(x_2, x_3)
\ge h(x_1, x_3) \\
& = D_f\big(f_0(2 x_1), f_0(2 x_3)\big)
= D_f(p_1, p_3).
\end{align}